# Angular6 + Cordova : cordova is not loaded

Tags: angular, cordova

I know this is a common issue but all the workarounds found were "*include cordova.js in index.html*" or "change href="." to href="./""

I think cordova API is not loaded in the application because deviceready callback is not called.
But I can still run the app (but components using navigagor.mediadevices doesn't work).

**index.html**

```
<base href="./">
<script src=”cordova.js”></script>
<script>
window.isready = false;
function ready(){
    alert('test');
    console.log('test');
    window.isready = true; // this is always false
}
document.addEventListener('deviceready', ready, false);
</script>
```

The event is never fired

**How i installed cordova & build the app**

```
npm install -g cordova
cordova create cordova
cd cordova && cordova platforms add android
rm -rf cordova/www/*
ng build --prod --aot --output-path=cordova/www
cd cordova && cordova build android
```

**cordova's package.json**

```
... 
"dependencies": {
    "cordova-android": "^7.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-file": "^6.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-media-capture": "^3.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3"
},
"cordova": {
    "plugins": {
        "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
        "cordova-plugin-media-capture": {},
        "cordova-plugin-device": {}
    },
    "platforms": [
        "android"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Are you running this on a device or in a web browser?

Comment: I am running on android device.
My goal is to share the same code for the web app and the mobile app.
PWAs are a great workaround but we need the app to be on play store & apple store.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The setup for your event handler of `deviceready` is correct. The problem appears to be your inclusion of `cordova.js`. Here's what you should do to troubleshoot:

1. In your code sample above, you've included `cordova.js` using slanted double quotes, instead of plain double quotes.

Try changing this:

`<script src=”cordova.js”></script>`

To this:

`<script src="cordova.js"></script>`

2. Run the app on your Android device, connect your device to your computer via USB, enabling developer mode debugging on your device, and open up `chrome://inspect` to live inspect the app as it's running. Make sure that `cordova.js` actually exists and that it was successfully loaded upon app boot.
3. The order in which you include `cordova.js` can make a difference. You may need to move `<script src="cordova.js"></script>` beneath the `<script>` block where you setup the `deviceready` event handler.

Comment: wow, how could i not see it before... This is the problem when you copy/paste a code from internet...

Thanks a lot, this resolved my problem.

Comment: No problem! Sometimes it just takes a second pair of eyes to catch the typo.